# error CS0234: Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs assembly/metadata file missing in azure function 2.0

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to create EventHub trigger azure function with many as cardinality for event message batching.

Following is code in run.csx

```
#r "Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs"

using System.Text;
using System;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;

public static void Run(EventData[] eventMessage, ILogger logger)
{
    logger.LogInformation("Event: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventMessage.Body)}");
    logger.LogInformation("EnqueuedTimeUtc={eventMessage.SystemProperties.EnqueuedTimeUtc}");
    logger.LogInformation("SequenceNumber={eventMessage.SystemProperties.SequenceNumber}");
    logger.LogInformation("Offset={eventMessage.SystemProperties.Offset}");

}
```

along runtime config host.json is

```
{
  "version": "2.0"
}
```

and function's config file function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
    "type": "eventHubTrigger",
    "name": "eventMessage",
    "direction": "in",
    "eventHubName": "myEventHub",
    "connection": "consumer_hub",
    "consumerGroup": "$Default",
    "cardinality": "many"
    }
  ]
}
```

After getting error on compilation regarding assemply is missing

```
2018-11-27T09:36:54.325 [Error] run.csx(1,1): error CS0006: Metadata file 'Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs' could not be found
2018-11-27T09:36:54.389 [Error] run.csx(5,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ServiceBus' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2018-11-27T09:36:54.425 [Error] run.csx(6,23): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'EventHubs' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Azure' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2018-11-27T09:36:54.522 [Error] run.csx(9,24): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'EventData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Could you please help me why dependency is not available in azure function? Even azure documentation has reference for this.That means this assemplies should already be present in runtime environment provided by azure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The doc is somehow inconsistent, have a try at code below.

```
#r "../bin/Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.dll"

using System.Text;
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;

public static void Run(EventData[] eventMessage, ILogger logger)
{
    foreach (var message in eventMessage)
    {
        logger.LogInformation($"Event: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}");
        logger.LogInformation($"EnqueuedTimeUtc={message.SystemProperties.EnqueuedTimeUtc}");
        logger.LogInformation($"SequenceNumber={message.SystemProperties.SequenceNumber}");
        logger.LogInformation($"Offset={message.SystemProperties.Offset}");
    }
}
```

Besides, in function.json, [cardinality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#trigger---configuration) is for js function to receive events in a batch. For c#, `EventData[]` is enough.

Comment: Its working. So we need to add external assembly for this.That's great help.

Comment: @OomphFortuity We were supposed to use `#r "Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs"`, but there's an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3637), we have to install storage extension to make the reference directive work, or we need to add relative path as I have found.

Comment: Thats great info.